# GIF animation stops when popup is displayed

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have a GIF which is set as the background image. When the alert message is invoked then the GIF animation stops and i want to avoid this. I want to run my GIF in the background and should not stop when the alert message is called.

This is my style to set the background gif

```
   <style>
    body {
        background-image:url(background.gif);
        background-size:100%;
        background-repeat: repeat-y;
        background-attachment: fixed;
        height:100%;
        width:100%;
    }

    </style>
```

Here i am showing the alert message.

```
  $(window).load(function(){
      function show_popup(){
      {     
        alert("testing");    
      };
       window.setTimeout( show_popup, 500 ); // 5 seconds
    })
```

Any help on this issue would be appreciated.Thanks in advance

Comment: I doubt you have any control over this behavior, and I imagine this behavior is browser specific. You might consider using a DOM-based dialog, and just not use `alert`.

Comment: `alert()` and `prompt()` stops the thread therefore stops all animations and network operation (ajax for example). If you want animations to work then don't use `alert()`

Comment: i have few alert messages and can not use dialog. is there any way to use the alert?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is part of the way a browser works. A browser page in single-threaded, meaning that every operation occurs in one queue. JavaScript `alert`s, `prompt`s, etc. are synchronous and block the single thread in its tracks until the user does something.

Therefore, the `alert` causes the whole webpage to just pause until it is dismissed by the user, causing the `gif` to pause as well.

To fix this issue, use a DOM-based dialog as AlexanderOMara suggested. If you are using jQuery, you could use the [jQuery UI dialog](https://jqueryui.com/dialog/)

Comment: i have few alert messages and can not use dialog. is there any way to use the alert?

Comment: @user3754676 "can not" - I think you mean "don't want to". Can you identify why you *don't want to* use dialogs, and we can see whether we can assist with that issue?

Comment: It's worth noting that not all browsers will block rendering for synchronous JavaScript. Firefox will continue to play animated GIF images and CSS animations, for better or worse.